# Date with and without spaces between dots

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, type-mismatch

I was facing with a type mismatch error in VBA and I have finally found the root cause but I don't know how to solve it.

The issue is if I call the Date function in VBA on my notebook, I get in the following format: "2023.04.25" (without spaces). If I do the same on my colleagues' notebooks, I get the date with spaces between the dots, like this: "2023. 04. 25". That's why the macro runs correctly on my notebook and show type mismatch error on my colleagues' notebooks. Any idea how to solve it? Can it be a basic setting or something like this?

```
            y1 = 3
            
            While IsEmpty(Cells(y1, 1)) = False
            Cells(y1, 1) = Replace(Cells(y1, 1), " ", "")
            Cells(y1, 1) = CDate(Cells(y1, 1))      <--- type mismatch error
            y1 = y1 + 1
            Wend
```

In the cells (y1,1) are dates and I wanted to check is there any space in the date or not. If yes, delete it. Everything was fine on my notebook, but I got type mismatch error on other notebook with the same VBA, same dates.

I tested the dates with the following code (dates from A3 to A15):

```
sub
Dim A As String
Dim B As Date
Dim i As Variant

For i = 3 To 15
    A = Cells(i, 1)
    B = CDate(A)
    Cells(i, 3) = B
Next
end sub
```

With this everything is fine on each notebook. If I use the replace command to delete spaces from the date cells, I got again type mismatch error.

Dates were copied from an excel file which was imported from SAP. Example: 2023.04.03.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please at least include the line that is displayed when the error happens in your question? If you could include more than that, that would also be great.

Comment: The `Date`-function is always returning a *Date* (which is internally a Number). What you see is the *representation* that may vary on computers (mine shows `25.04.2023`). That alone gives you no type mismatch. You need to show your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code there (and don't forget to format it as code). As a comment it is unreadable

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. Question is updated with the codes. Please note that the VBA file and the source of dates (from where we copy the dates) were totally the same. On my notebook everything fine, on other notebook type mismatch error Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `CDate`-function cannot convert the contents in the cell *Cells(y1, 1)*  to a date. The dates need to be formatted in a way that `CDate` can interpret, so either change the cell format or make sure the string-handling before the conversion is working as intended.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It is strange because it works well on my notebook with the same data and same vba code.

What if I do like this:

            While IsEmpty(Cells(y1, 1)) = False /////
            y1s = Replace(Cells(y1, 1), " ", "") /////
            y1d = CDate(y1s) /////
            Cells(y1, 1) = y1d /////
            y1 = y1 + 1 /////
            Wend /////

So, first I put the content of cells(y1,1) to a variable, then convert it to date with CDate.

Comment: Back to your comment to change the cell format. I have already tried it with the following command: Range("A3:A15").NumberFormat = "yyyy.mm.dd;@", the issue was the same. And it was before the CDate command.

Comment: If the same code and data work differently on different machines, there must be sometheing else that differs - check and compare the date-settings for the operating system on the computers.

Comment: UPDATE: without the Replace command, everything is fine on each notebook. If I use the Replace command and try to convert with CDate, doesn't work. Any ide why? I have already tried to convert to string, then replace, then convert to date, everything. The result is the same. It work only without replace command. Thanks!

Comment: What is the goal of your code? If the cell already contains a date (and not a string that more or less looks like a date), `Replace` will convert it into a string, and (again on regional settings) `CDate` might or might not be able to convert it back to a date. If it is already a date, your code is pointless at all.

Comment: The goal would be to remove spaces from the dates because sometimes colleagues found spaces in the dates after dots and in these cases they experienced error messages. The root cause is definitely the replace command. If I don't use it, everything fine on each notebook. If I use replace command, everything is fine on my notebook, but we got error messages on other notebooks. Any idea why is it different on other notebooks? You mentioned that it depends on the regional settings. Any further information about this? Thank you!

Comment: Again: What is the content of the cells: A date or a string? How are the cells filled (where does the data come from)? Select the cell in Excel, switch to VBA and enter in the immediate window `? vartype(activecell)`: 5 means you have a number (`vbDouble`), 7 means you have a `Date` and 8 means you have a `String`.

Comment: The problem is that the contet of the cells can be different depending on where the data come from. It is a macro for the working hours calculation, so data can came from other excel, from this macro with a button, etc. (depending on the user). That's why I wanted to remove spaces (if necessary), then convert it to date. And I also tried .numberformat="dd.mm.yyyy". Result from the immediate window is 7, so it should be date. I have also tried to convert to string with CStr, replace command, then convert to date with CDate. No way with replace.

Comment: Use `Replace` to replace the `Dot` with a `Space`, assuming your date variations are just what you have written.  Then apply `CDate` to the replaced string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `Replace` twice:

```vb
While IsEmpty(Cells(y1, 1)) = False
    Cells(y1, 1) = CDate(Replace(Replace(Cells(y1, 1), " ", ""), ".", "-"))
    y1 = y1 + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works! :) Could you please explain me the logic behind?

Comment: Yes. First it removes the offending spaces, then replaces the dots (which are typical for German date separators) with a _dash_ that `CDate` understands as a date separator, thus can convert the final string (like 2023-04-25) to a true date value.

Comment: Understood, thanks :) But it is still strange for me that it worked well on my notebook, but my colleagues got type mismatch error with the same code and data.

One more question. I experienced that if I use togther Format and CDate, the result will be string. If I use CDate, then Format, the result is date. // a = Format(CDate(b), "YYYY.MM.DD") -> result string. // a = CDate(b) <new line> place
.NumberFormat = "yyyy.mm.dd;@" -> result date

Comment: That's because `Format` returns _text_, which is just that, while `CDate` (and `DateValue`) returns _DateTime_, which you later can apply any format for _display_, including `yyyy.mm.dd`.